# Where can I find the documentation for "Nullable friendly pattern"?

Tags: c#

In https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification.md#element-access the following code is used, which I don't understand and I haven't found any documentation:

```
// Nullable friendly pattern
if (array[0] is { } o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}
```

My incomprehension refers to the empty curly brackets. Where is documented how to understand / use this.
Is it possible to use this scheme "{ } var-name" in another place or is it bound to the usage with the is-operator?

Comment: "Where can I find documentation" is a bad question. "What is nullable friendly pattern and how to use it" would be a better question.

Comment: @Guy Incognito: I am looking for both, but the documentation in the first place.

Comment: @Julian People pretty consistently confuse "I don't understand the question" with "the question is unclear."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of the C# pattern matching language feature, although not named explicitly as such.

The documentation about [recursive pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern) mentions it in the property pattern section, showing the ways to check for not null giving an example for a `string`.

> Note that a null-checking pattern falls out of a trivial property
> pattern. To check if the string s is non-null, you can write any of the following forms

```
if (s is object o) ... // o is of type object
if (s is string x) ... // x is of type string
if (s is {} x) ... // x is of type string
if (s is {}) ...
```

---

A [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/pattern-matching) gives an other example where being used in a `switch` statement and specifies

> The { } case matches any non-null object that didn't match an earlier arm.

```
public decimal CalculateToll(object vehicle) => vehicle switch
{
    Car c           => 2.00m,
    Taxi t          => 3.50m,
    Bus b           => 5.00m,
    DeliveryTruck t => 10.00m,
    { }             => throw new ArgumentException(message: "Not a known vehicle type", paramName: nameof(vehicle)),
    null            => throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vehicle))
};
```

---

What happens is that `if (array[0] is { } o)` gets translated into `if (array[0] != null)`.
You can see it at https://sharplab.io

Comment: So is it correct to interpret `if (s is string x)` as "if `s` has a type (i.e., `s` is not null) and that type is `string`"?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede That is correct, for `if (s is string x)` `s` will be a `string` which is not null.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and to everyone else also for your support.